# Changing font format of given line,column of a document

Tags: docx, doc, python-docx

Let's we have a `docx` file containing a page of information. Let's assume it has 30 lines where each line has 20 to 50 characters. Now what I need is to change the format i.e. `font, size, bold/normal, italic/non-italic` of some of letters from that doc file.

**What I did?**

Firstly, I was clueless. Then got the **python-docx** library. It gives api to get access to text. But changing the format is a long way to walk.

Is there any better way to get the job done? It can be any language/library solution. 
Or if there is any better way by converting the doc file to any other file type and then doing the job - also exceptable.